# Standby Problem, PC can not enter Standby mode

Tags: 14.04, suspend, nouveau

I have a problem with the Standby function: My Computer does not enter the Standby mode with Ubuntu 14.04LTS. If I remeber me right, it works with Ubuntu 13.10 but this Version was not long installed on this PC.
Now when i press Standby in the menu or on my Keyboard, the display turns black for a few seconds, then some messages appear for a very short moment on the screen. After that, the the log-in screen appear. Two times I was able to enter Standby but the other times it fails.

Tecnical Data about my PC:

Ubuntu 14.04 with all Updates

main storage: 3,8GiB

processor: Intel® Core™ i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4

graphic: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile
graphic board: NVIDA GEFORCE GT 555M CUDA 1GB

Dual Boot System with win7
x64Bit Medion P6812 Laptop

Here is the message output:
[image: messages]
Usally I got only a half or one third of the screen filled with messages like that. This time, when I filmed it, it was much more.

here is the log from `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`:

```
Initial commandline parameters: 
Wed Aug 20 17:09:25 CEST 2014: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux leon-P6812 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 13 15:45:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
dm_crypt               23177  1 
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 52570  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
ctr                    13049  0 
ccm                    17773  0 
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bnep                   19624  2 
bluetooth             391196  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
rts5139               335409  0 
arc4                   12608  2 
iwldvm                232285  0 
mac80211              630653  1 iwldvm
acer_wmi               32522  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 acer_wmi
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm_intel             143060  0 
kvm                   451511  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46254  1 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    61438  1 
cryptd                 20359  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_hda_intel          52355  5 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
joydev                 17381  0 
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
serio_raw              13462  0 
snd_pcm               102099  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
lpc_ich                21080  0 
iwlwifi               169932  1 iwldvm
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
snd                    69238  20 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mei_me                 18627  0 
mei                    82276  1 mei_me
parport_pc             32701  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
usb_storage            62209  1 
nouveau              1097199  1 
i915                  783805  4 
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
psmouse               106678  0 
ttm                    85115  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           13413  2 i915,nouveau
ahci                   25819  3 
drm_kms_helper         53081  2 i915,nouveau
libahci                32560  1 ahci
drm                   303102  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
atl1c                  46086  0 
wmi                    19177  3 acer_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  19476  3 i915,acer_wmi,nouveau
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3951564    3708976     242588     395912      49344    1329840
-/+ buffers/cache:    2329792    1621772
Swap:      4092924      12240    4080684
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
stop: Unknown instance: 
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.

Wed Aug 20 17:09:25 CEST 2014: performing suspend
sh: echo: I/O error
Wed Aug 20 17:09:29 CEST 2014: Awake.
Wed Aug 20 17:09:29 CEST 2014: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
Reloaded unloaded modules.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.

Wed Aug 20 17:09:30 CEST 2014: Finished.
```

Output of lspci:

```
leon@leon-P6812:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF116M [GeForce GT 555M/635M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
05:00.0 USB controller: Texas Instruments TUSB73x0 SuperSpeed USB 3.0 xHCI Host Controller (rev 02)
```

Maybe related to this unanswered question: [Standby Mode (suspend) not working on my computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380078/standby-mode-suspend-not-working-on-my-computer)
If someone needs more log comment. I dont know wich logs are necessary in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the default nouveau driver, for your nvidia graphics card. This is a reverse engineered driver and is known to cause trouble with power management. 
From what I can tell from my experience suspend with nouveau is gambling, depends very much on the kernel version, graphics card etc.

The first thing I would try if I were you is installing the official nvidia driver: Note, though, it is proprietary, but I would try to see if it resolves your problem, because then we know pretty much for sure nouveau is the component to blame. (Looking at all the errors on your screen I am pretty sure though nouveau is the trouble maker.)
If you have concern because the proprietary driver is closed source, you can set up a second ubuntu install on an external hdd/usb and try it there.

To try the proprietary nvidia driver do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

and reboot your machine after the process finished.

Please report back if that changes something for you.

If not, my second try would be disconnecting all external hardware (usb devices like scanners, printers etc.), to make sure nothing external triggers a wakeup.

EDIT: Please also paste the output of

```
lspci
```

since the error message on your screen says "Device 0000:01:00.0 failed to suspend" and that command helps us to find what device exactly that is, but I suppose your graphics card.

Added by questioner:
For all who have similar Problem with a Nvidia Card in a laptop, If you have further trouble (eg. if your OpenGL Version is still low, or your laptop needs a lot of energy), check if your card uses [**OPTIMUS** technology](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/optimus). This means that you have an additional graphics card, which is used for not graphical expensive Applications. In contrast this second card is optimized for low energy usage. You can search on the in the optimus scetion on the [Nvidia Site](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/optimus/supported-gpus) for your card. If found your card there install also `bumblebee` and `bumblebee-nvidia`. After that, to run a Application with your powerful graphics card you have to run your Application via

```
$ optirun <path to app>
```

Comment: Is nouveau reversed engineered? I was under the impression it was just an opensource alternative.

Comment: Yeah it is, because nvidia does not release enough hardware information. Read the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_(software).
You are maybe confusing this with drivers for AMD graphic cards, where the situation is a little different.

Comment: Go to the nvidia site and get the proprietary drivers, I had a similar problem

Comment: peterretief: I would not recommend this, simply use the packaged version available from the repo, otherwise it will break everytime you do an kernel upgrade. If the packaged version(s) are too outdated for you, I have good experiences with https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa, be careful though.

Comment: Leon95, I am glad it works! The graphics performance will also be a lot better, than with the nouveau driver and your system will likely be more power efficient.

Comment: I was having trouble for some time with suspend.. IT totally solved the problem.. Thanks a loooooooooooooooot..