# Suspend is not working in Ubuntu, NVIDIA Graphics card is installed

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, suspend

In my newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Suspend is not working. I tried to do it with `sudo s2ram`. I am getting a message

```
KMS graphics driver is in use, skipping quirks.
```

I also tried `sudo pm-suspend` with both of them the computer is going to sleep. When I press any button in the keyboard or the power button it woke up, but when it woke up, the screen freezes. I have tried some posts, but to no avail. I have added the links which I have tried.

[Link 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383880/how-do-i-get-suspend-working-on-an-hp-dv4t), [Link 2](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/fix-for-suspend-and-hibernation-problem-for-laptops.html), [Link 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver)

I always put my computer to sleep, but this problem has made using the computer practically impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem by running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

Now I can use suspend without any fuzz. I came across [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513876/standby-problem-pc-can-not-enter-standby-mode?rq=1) and my pc is working just fine. The nouveau driver it has some problem with the power management. Once the latest driver for the Nvidia is installed, it has solved the problem on it's own.

Comment: so you mean you can put your computer to sleep and wake it without any problems like screen freeze or black screen etc?

Comment: Yes exactly. The problem I had is gone. Now it is possible to put the computer in sleep mode and then when I wake it up, It has all the program I had opened before I put it into sleep. And the screen does not freeze as well.

Answer (score 2):

try to install pm-utils and suspend pc with pm-suspend command.

Comment: It is already installed and I have tried it before. But sudo pm-suspend does not work as well.

Comment: Is there any useful information in `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`?

Comment: @DougSmythies Hey, sorry for late reply. I have added the output of /var/log/pm-suspend.log please, take a look and help me if possible.

Comment: Only this solution helped me out of all described on the internet. Ubuntu 21.04 with noouveau drivers woke immediately afte suspend, or did not want to go to suspend at all. pm-suspend works like a charm.